# On pairwise non-disjointness of a sequence of finite sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ be a sequence of finite sets such that no two sets of the sequence are pairwise disjoint ; then must there exist a finite set $F$ such that no two sets in the sequence $\{ A_n \cap F\}_{n=1}^\infty $ are pairwise disjoint ?

Comment: I think it would improve the title to say "nondisjointness" rather than "disjointness" for the sake of consistency with the body of the Question.

Comment: @hardmath : right . Edited . Thanks

Comment: Makes me think of Helley's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem

Comment: @users : Right, I got turned around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample.** For $n\in\mathbb N$ define
$$A_n=\{x\in\mathbb N:x\le n\ \text{ and }\ x\equiv n\!\!\!\!\!\pmod2\}\cup\{n+1\}.$$

The sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ are pairwise intersecting: for $m\lt n,$ if $m$ and $n$ have the same parity, then $m\in A_m\cap A_n;$ otherwise, $m+1\in A_m\cap A_n;$ in either case, $A_m\cap A_n\ne\emptyset.$

If $F\subseteq\mathbb N$ is such that the sets $A_1\cap F,A_2\cap F,A_3\cap F,\dots$ are pairwise intersecting, then we must have $F=\mathbb N,$ since $A_n\cap A_{n+1}=\{n+1\}$ and $A_1\cap A_3=\{1\}.$

Comment: Wow! Nice construction . Is there any counterexample satisfying $|A_n|=|A_{n+1}|,\forall n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @users I doubt it. I suspect that you *can* get a finite set $F$ when the $A_n$ are bounded in size. But I wouldn't know offhand how to prove that. That's worth another question.

Comment: I asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473188/on-pairwise-non-disjointness-of-a-sequence-of-finite-sets-whose-sizes-are-unifor , with you condition of the sequence $A_n$ being of uniformly bounded size .